# How can i exit from my Android App in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using the react-native-router-flux latest version **"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6"** and **"react-native": "0.60.5"**. I tried many alternatives but couldn't get any success. I want to exit the native App from my home scene from physical devices or from the Emulator. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Router>
  <Stack key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
    <Scene key="Home" component={Home} title="Home" initial={true} type={ActionConst.RESET}/>
    <Scene key="Categories" component={Categories} title="Categories"/>
  </Stack>
</Router>

//Home.js
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
  }

  handleBackButtonClick() {
      BackHandler.exitApp();
      return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put this **backAndroidHandler** in your main *Router*:

with **Actions.currentScene** you will get the the **Scene** you are in it

```
                  <Router     
                      backAndroidHandler={() => {
                        let cs = Actions.currentScene;
                        if (cs === 'Home') {return false } 
                        else {Actions.pop()}
                       }}
                   >
```